# Не работает анимация в React Native Web

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Хочу сделать обычный Progress Bar, но не выходит.

App.tsx:

```
const [progress, setProgress] =  useState(0);
...
useEffect(() => {

   setInterval(() => {
     setProgress(progress + 1)
   }, 1000);

}
});
...
return (
...
<ProgressBar progress={progress} />
...
)
```

ProgressBar.tsx:

```
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { View, Animated } from "react-native";

type ProgressBarProps = {
  progress: number
}

const ProgressBar: React.FC<ProgressBarProps> = (props) => {
  const animation = new Animated.Value(props.progress);

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: props.progress,
      duration: 500
    }).start();

    console.log(props.progress)
  });

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 4}}>
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width: animation.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: ["0%", "100%"],
            extrapolate: "clamp"
          }),
          height: '10px',
          backgroundColor: 'red'
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProgressBar;
```

В итоге просто красная короткая линия выводится на страницу.
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/merrymaker14/react-native-web-example-as-testtask

Comment: Вопрос еще актуальный?

Comment: Да, конечно: так и не решилось.

Comment: посмотри ниже ;) ⬇️

Comment: ответ принимается? @timurmusharapov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лови! 
можно как useRef так и useState использовать для значений, которые не будут пересоздаваться на протяжении всего lifecycle компонента. 
Вторая проблема была в useEffect, надо таймер выключать ;)
ну и сам прогресс от 0 до 1 (чуть не забыл ;))

```
const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setProgress(Math.random());
    }, 2000);
    return () => clearInterval(timer);
  }, [setProgress]);

  return <ProgressBar key="progress" progress={progress} />;
};
```

```
const ProgressBar: React.FC<ProgressBarProps> = props => {
  const [{ animation, width }] = useState(() => {
    const animation = new Animated.Value(0);
    const width = animation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 1],
      outputRange: ["0%", "100%"],
      extrapolate: "clamp"
    });
    return { animation, width };
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(animation, {
      toValue: props.progress,
      duration: 500
    }).start();
    console.log(props.progress);
  }, [props.progress, animation]);

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, borderColor: "red", borderWidth: 2, borderRadius: 4 }}
    >
      <Animated.View
        style={{
          width,
          height: "10px",
          backgroundColor: "red"
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-web-example-as-testtask-g667e